# how to remove tags with jsoup but keep given tags

Tags: java, html, jsoup

How to remove all tags except `<p>` and `<img>` with jsoup?

```
<div>
  <p>hello world
    <span>good</span>
    <img src="/src/img/beauty.jpg"/>
    welcome
  </p>
</div>
```

Should become

```
<p>hello world
    good
    <img src="/src/img/beauty.jpg"/>
    welcome
  </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to look at the [Cleaner.clean() method](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Cleaner.html). You'll specify a [Whitelist](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html) of tags you want to allow.

[Example from jsoup.org](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer):

```
String unsafe = 
    "<p><a href='http://example.com/' onclick='stealCookies()'>Link</a></p>";
String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());
    // now: <p><a href="http://example.com/" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p>
```